# Is this function $f(x f(x)+y)=x^{2}+f(y)$ onto ??

Tags: functions, functional-equations

**question** -

Is this function $f(x f(x)+y)=x^{2}+f(y)$ onto $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

I just need to know that is this function is onto or not ...
by putting $y=0$ and $f(0)=s$ , 
I get $f(x f(x))=x^2 + s$ but i am not able to find an x such that $f(x)=y$ ...

any help will be appreciated

thankyou

Comment: Question on same equation by same user, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631355/find-all-functions-f-such-that-fx-fxy-x2fy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $a:=f(1)$, we have
$$ f(a+y)=1+f(y)$$
hence by induction 
$$\tag1 f(na+y)=n+f(y)$$
for all $n\in\Bbb N$, and by letting $y\leftarrow y-na$ also
$$ f(y)=n+f(y-na)$$
i.e., $(1)$ holds for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. 
In particular,
$$ f(na)=n+f(0)\qquad\text{for }n\in\Bbb Z.$$
Given $z\in \Bbb R$, let $n=\lfloor z-f(0)\rfloor$ and $y=na$ so that $f(y)\le z$. 
Now let  $x=\sqrt {z-f(y)}$ to find
$$ f(xf(x)+y)=x^2+f(y)=z.$$